Proper use of quotes in a command substitution - how?
In a rather large project, I run into the following problem: while calculating the correct command in a bash script, I don't manage to make the script respect the double quote necessary for single arguments with a blank.
$ ./testo "two three"
ls -l "two three_DD_FF"  # <- Why does it look for two files HERE??
ls: cannot access '"two': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'three_DD_FF"': No such file or directory

"two three" is the single argument.
With two_three my code works, as to be expected:
$ ./testo two_three
ls -l "two_three_DD_FF"
ls: cannot access '"two_three_DD_FF"': No such file or directory

And this is the basic generic code that I could come up with:
#!/usr/bin/bash
cmd="ls -l"
trio=""'"'"${1}_DD"
trio="${cmd} ${trio}_FF"'"'""
echo ${trio}
${trio}


(I didn't find a less strange method than the one above for the strangely looking strong quote, but that is not my main concern here.)
What I don't understand is the problem in execution:
ls -l "two three_DD_FF"
in the line above still leads to searching for two files, despite of the double quotes; while the same line on the command prompt does a job as intended (that is, searching for file "two three_DD_FF":
$ ls -l "two three_DD_FF"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myhome me 0 Aug 27 13:09 'two three_DD_FF'

That is, the line echo ${trio} shows a correct command (when executed on the command line, at least; while the same command, when executed from within a script, fails. It fails to respect the double quotes for the file name to be searched.
My questions:

Why does the same command fail from within a script?
Of course, how do I rectify the script, so that the call actually results in the correct output?


Your ls could be some weird alias check like this type ls

Quoting "two three" helps them be a single argument in $1 instead of getting split into $1, $2. But if you were to then run ls -l $1, which is basically what you're doing, since $1 isn't quoted, it will be split. In other words, quotes aren't "preserved" in the variable. You seem to already understand this, since otherwise by your logic cmd="ls -l" shouldn't work either, since it would not be split.

Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. Imo no amount of quote could fix your script

This question is similar to: Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The quotes embedded in trio are literal, not syntactical, so they cannot be used to prevent word splitting.

What answer do you get when you do a type ls?

Clarify: The script testso, you are calling here, is the odd small bash script you posted in your question?

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't run their script through http://shellcheck.net first as instructed by the [tag:bash] tag.

The way you call the script what you write in the script matters. If you write unquoted ${trio} it is always going to split on spaces no matter the content. You have to write constructs in the script that prevent splitting, but using quotes that you write, not generate, for example ls -l "$trio". You can't store commands in a variable - use function to store commands. Required reading https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

Thanks for the hint with arrays. And thanks to the hint of @Ed Morton.
However, closing the question because someone(who??) decided it wasn't about programming and voting it down is ridiculous. A question-site isn't supposed to scare off users from asking questions that others perceive as "too basic", or whatnot.

Unfortunately there is no specific close reason to click on for "didn't follow the tag instructions", you need to manually type that, and the site just picks one of the set it has available to click on to show as the close reason if anyone clicked on one of them. Your question wasn't in reality closed for not being about programming or being too basic, it was because the code contains errors that shellcheck, which the [tag:bash] tag you used tells you to use before posting a bash question, would have told you about (and so the many people reading your code wouldn't have to address).

@udippel : One problem with your question is, that you asked two questions (why does it fail? How do I write it better?), and here you see why: User Wiimm gave you a better why to do it, but no explanation why your code fails. I gave you an explanation why it fails, but no alternative solution. Now, if you want to accept an answer, which of the two could you accept? This is the main reason why you should have only one question present - this will allow you to select the best answer.

In addition, your tagging is weird. You tagged this for instance as double, although there isn't anything related to the C or C++ double type in your question. Also, I don't see much relevance of the execution tag, since you don't have a problem to actually start/execute a process.

My recommendation: work with arrays:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cmd=(ls -l)
trio=( "${cmd[@]}" "${1}_DD_FF" )
"${trio[@]}"


Replacing the echo in your script by a xxd <<< ${trio}, we can see:
00000000: 6c73 202d 6c20 2274 776f 2074 6872 6565  ls -l "two three
00000010: 5f44 445f 4646 220a                      _DD_FF".

Your variable trio therefore contains the string ls -l "two three_DD_FF".
When you run ${trio}, which could be written simpler as $trio, bash applies word splitting on the string, which gives the following words:
0: ls
1: -l
2: "two
3: three_DD_FF"

Hence ls is called with an option parameter (-l) and two additional arguments, "two and three_DD_FF".
This is reflected in the error message about not finding "two and three_DD_FF".

Nice clear answer.  But why do you have backticks on the first two items in your 0-4 list?  It should just be: 0: ls then 1: -l then 2: "two then 3: three_DD_FF".

@Raven: No idea why they got there. I removed them. Thanks for telling me.
